# The function executed per second , it works,but like to per 0.5 sec

Tags: c++, time

Greeting !!

The following code works fine....at least more than one second will execute expx function 
in function Getexp , I called Getexp every 0.01 second for 100 times, 
actually expx function will be called just one time only , that is what I want !!

But , my user need to change to at least more than 0.5 second to call expx , 
since the following code works in tick1 , tick2 in integer type , 
I need advice to change not too many codes below and will satisfy user needs ....

What function will be best suitable foe my case ? time_t won't work for me in 0.5 sec case!

```
double Getexp(double valuex)
{
    double wgt=0.9 ;
    static double value_t0=0.0 ;
    static double value_t1=0.0 ;
    double dret = 0.0 ;
    static time_t tick1=0 ,tick2=0 ;

    if(value_t0 < 0.0001)
    {
        tick1=time(NULL);
        tick2=tick1 ;
        value_t0 = valuex ;
        value_t1 = valuex ;
        dret = expx(value_t1,value_t0,wgt) ;
        value_t0 = dret ;
        return value_t0   ;
    }
    tick2=time(NULL);
    if(tick2 > tick1)
    {
        tick1 = tick2 ;
        value_t1 = valuex ;
        dret = expx(value_t1,value_t0,wgt) ;
        value_t0 = dret ;
        return value_t0 ;
    }else
    {
        return value_t0  ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather difficult to assess what is being asked.  But I suspect you are complaining that "time()" just has accuracy to the nearest second, but you need sub-second accuracy.

Some clock functions to explore instead of calling "time".

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows)

[GetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows)

[gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday)

[clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)

In other words, consider converting your code to process time in terms of milliseconds and use one of the appropriate calls above to get the that time

Answer (score 0):

I guess your 'time(NULL)' don't have the precision you want. If it had say 10msec precision you'd call expx 100 times per second...

You need a high precision timer and then you shouldn't do timer1=timer2; but timer1=timer2 + DELAY;
Where DELAY is the time you don't wan't to call expx.

Sometimes timers give the time in milliseconds, that doesn't mean they have a millisecond precision though. For example, if I recall correctly, the windows timer can have a 25-50msec precision at worst.

Comment: I've tested it in gcc...time(NULL) will be the seconds since January 1, 1970 , I refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/  , so if what I want is integer like 1 second , 2 seconds or more , it works fine , but user request 0.5 second , it won't work in time_t , or I don't know how to change my code to fit 0.5 second case...thanks for your kind response !

Comment: If you use GetTickCount for example and change your code with my remark (timer1=timer2 + DELAY;) where DELAY is in milliseconds (500 for each 0.5 sec) then it will work perfectly.